# Inconsistent behavior in pandas read_excel MultiIndex table

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

I am trying to read a table from the middle of an Excel spreadsheet. I kept getting an `Error: "ValueError: Length of new names must be 1, got 2"`, so I investigated.

The data is as follows (names/numbers anonymized from actual data):

```
N       CAT M1                      M2  
            X           Y           X           Y
NO.1    a   0.41643788  0.88942373  0.26933274  0.95977932
        b   0.28689039  0.87526651  0.96954965  0.68133285
        c   0.10116878  0.88546464  0.58168584  0.90003147
NO.2    a   0.76601712  0.78037294  0.00491586  0.83316633
        b   0.0712588   0.37220828  0.47436415  0.64341387
        c   0.85379943  0.81726821  0.22535168  0.48287717
NO.3    a   0.41222094  0.19984605  0.09910102  0.02424937
        b   0.55276466  0.11485025  0.49249596  0.92750493
        c   0.3392061   0.71785127  0.04407181  0.8971764
NO.4    a   0.13319829  0.79513987  0.58707957  0.1328719
        b   0.72346756  0.42838316  0.81403618  0.96184934
        c   0.14540022  0.81240023  0.960625    0.05436801
```

I created two spreadsheets to isolate the issue:

- `test_sheet.xlsx` contains the data in the range `A1:F14`.
- `test_sheet_fails.xlsx` contains the data in the range `D8:I21`.

I run the following two lines to read in the table to a pandas `DataFrame`:

```py
tf = pd.read_excel('test_sheet.xlsx', header=[0, 1], index_col=[0, 1])
tf_fail = pd.read_excel('test_sheet_fails.xlsx', header=[8, 9], index_col=[3, 4])
```

`tf` imports as expected, with a `MultiIndex` for both index and columns. `tf_fail` gives the same `Error: "ValueError: Length of new names must be 1, got 2"` error.

Why can pandas not read the same table when it is offset from the "A1" cell? Is there something I am missing in the documentation?

(Note: I have also tried clearing the cells "N" and "CAT", and get the same results.)

#### Versions

- Python: 3.8.3
- Pandas: 1.0.5
- conda: 4.8.3